# can I send request to django /admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework for a simple project. this api doesn't need registration and login for normal users. but it has an admin section on the frontend that can remove or add something to the website(to the database).

Do I need to create a customized ProfileApi App (Login and Authentication App that overrides the default Authentication that django has provided) for having these Possibilities. Or can i send request to /admin url or another url and login and get a token without having trouble of creating another app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use DRF permission class [IsAdminUser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isadminuser) for these views

```
class MyAdminView(..):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, ]

    # rest of view here
```